# Multiplayer invitation not received by android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-games

I am using playgameservices unity plugin to implement realtime multiplayer gaming. I successfully set up APNs to receive multiplayer invitations on iOS devices. But when I switch to Android, I did not see any notification both when running or not running the application.

I think I am missing something very basic, but, from scratch, what should I do to enable notifications for this purpose on Android side? i.e. in manifest file, on developer console etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that the synchronization on my Android device is disabled. So, just enabling "sync" did the trick. 
See https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/525 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure you have the latest version of Google Play Services installed.

The procedure in android to accept the invitation is relatively simple. You have to implement a callback [OnInvitationReceivedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/OnInvitationReceivedListener.html). This callback is invoked when a new invitation is received. This allows an app to respond to the invitation as appropriate. If you send an invite to a player with the game NOT running, Google Play Services on his phone should receive a request. The player can then accept or decline that invitation.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I did all and my problem was something different.